# Adding component's title to an array list within React, best implementation

Tags: reactjs, components

I have several components with buttons. When user clicks on buttons the specific component should be added to an array list named "list"

Here is how I implemented the logic.

First,
This is my component:

```
import './card.css';

export default function Card({ title, setList, list }) {
  return (
    <div className="bg">
      <h2 className="color">{title}</h2>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setList([...list, title]);
          alert(list);
        }}
      >
        click to add
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And this is my app:

```
import data from './data';
function App() {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map((item) => {
        return (
          <Card
            key={item.id}
            title={item.title}
            list={list}
            setList={setList}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

It perfectly works, but my question is as I implemented the logic inside my component, React needs to create that function for every single component, and it wont be efficient at all I suppose.
Plus, I defined a useState hook and passed its values (both the variable and function) into my component which I dont know doing so makes sense or not!

What would be the best professional solution? Am I following the standards?

Comment: nope. as far as i know, doing that is fine with react.

Comment: @sean-7777 you mean it is ok to implement that function inside th component?